# Azure Disk Encryption using terraform VM extension - forces replacement [Second run]

Tags: encryption, terraform, lifecycle, azure-keyvault, terraform-provider-azure

I created the following resource to encrypt 'All' disk of a VM, and it worked fine so far:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm_encry_win" {
  count                         = "${var.vm_encry_os_type == "Windows" ? 1 : 0}"
  name                          = "${var.vm_encry_name}"
  location                      = "${var.vm_encry_location}"
  resource_group_name           = "${var.vm_encry_rg_name}"
  virtual_machine_name          = "${var.vm_encry_vm_name}"
  publisher                     = "${var.vm_encry_publisher}"
  type                          = "${var.vm_encry_type}"
  type_handler_version          = "${var.vm_encry_type_handler_version == "" ? "2.2" : var.vm_encry_type_handler_version}"
  auto_upgrade_minor_version    = "${var.vm_encry_auto_upgrade_minor_version}"
  tags                          = "${var.vm_encry_tags}"

  settings = <<SETTINGS
                {
                    "EncryptionOperation":      "${var.vm_encry_operation}",
                    "KeyVaultURL":              "${var.vm_encry_kv_vault_uri}",
                    "KeyVaultResourceId":       "${var.vm_encry_kv_vault_id}",
                    "KeyEncryptionKeyURL":      "${var.vm_encry_kv_key_url}",
                    "KekVaultResourceId":       "${var.vm_encry_kv_vault_id}",
                    "KeyEncryptionAlgorithm":   "${var.vm_encry_key_algorithm}",
                    "VolumeType":               "${var.vm_encry_volume_type}"
                }
             SETTINGS
}
```

When i ran the first time - ADE encryption is done for both OS and data disk.
However, When I re-run terraform using terraform plan or terraform apply, it wants to replace all my data disks I have already created, like the following screenshot illustrates.

[image]

I do not know how to solve it. And my already created disks should not be replaced.
I check on the lines of `ignore_chnages`

```
lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = [encryption_settings]
    }
```

I am not sure where to add or does this reference actually solves the problem?
Which resource block should i add them.
Or is there another way ?

Comment: Does [this solution](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/486) work for you? or you don't know where to add the [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#lifecycle-lifecycle-customizations)?

Comment: This solution did - work for me. i have to add in `azurerm_managed_disk` resource block. But i have kept this resource inside a module.

Comment: If this issue is solved, you may add an answer below that other members will benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine_extension" "vm_encry_win" {
  count                         = var.vm_encry_os_type == "Windows" ? 1 : 0
  name                          = var.vm_encry_name
  location                      = var.vm_encry_location
  resource_group_name           = var.vm_encry_rg_name
  virtual_machine_name          = var.vm_encry_vm_name
  publisher                     = var.vm_encry_publisher
  type                          = var.vm_encry_type
  type_handler_version          = var.vm_encry_type_handler_version == "" ? "2.2" : var.vm_encry_type_handler_version
  auto_upgrade_minor_version    = var.vm_encry_auto_upgrade_minor_version
  tags                          = var.vm_encry_tags

  settings = jsonencode({
    EncryptionOperation      = var.vm_encry_operation
    KeyVaultURL              = var.vm_encry_kv_vault_uri
    KeyVaultResourceId       = var.vm_encry_kv_vault_id
    KeyEncryptionKeyURL      = var.vm_encry_kv_key_url
    KekVaultResourceId       = var.vm_encry_kv_vault_id
    KeyEncryptionAlgorithm   = var.vm_encry_key_algorithm
    VolumeType               = var.vm_encry_volume_type
  })

  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      settings,     # This prevents unnecessary replacement for updates to the settings block
    ]
  }
}
```

In this updated code, the ignore_changes attribute is used for the settings block. This will prevent Terraform from replacing the data disks during future updates when changes occur to the settings block.